# PostgreSQL Query Performance Fluctuates

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

We have a system that loads data and then conducts data QC in PostgreSQL. The QC function's performance fluctuates drastically in one of our environments with no apparent pattern. I was able to track down the performance of the following simple query in the QC function:

```
WITH foo AS (SELECT full_address, jsonb_agg (gad_rec_id) gad_rec_ids
            FROM azgiv.v_full_addresses 
            WHERE gad_gly_id = 495
            GROUP BY full_address 
            HAVING count(1) > 1)
SELECT gad_nguid, gad_rec_id, foo.full_address
        FROM azgiv.v_full_addresses JOIN foo
            ON foo.full_address = v_full_addresses.full_address
        AND v_full_addresses.gad_gly_id = 495;
```

When I ran into slow-performance situation (Fig 2), I had to ANALYZE the table behind the view before the query plan changes to fast (Fig 1). The v_full_addresses is a simple view of a partitioned table with bunch of columns concatenated.

Here are two images of the query plans for the above query.  I am newbie when comes to understanding query optimization and any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Fast query Plan]
&
[image: Slow query plan]

Comment: The images are hard to read and contain little information.  You should show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` as text.

Comment: It might be a typo or a simplification for StackOverflow but as far as I can see the result of the `jsonb_agg()` isn't used anywhere in the query further on; leaving it out might save you some CPU cycles. Also, if I may ask, what did you use to create those query plan diagrams?

Comment: @deroby  I used PgAdmin IV to generate the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

If performance improves after you `ANALYZE` a table, that means that the database's knowledge about the distribution of the data is outdated.

The best remedy is to tell PostgreSQL to collect these statistics more often:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table SET (autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.02);
```

0.02 is five times lower than the default 0.1, so statistics will be gathered five times more often.

If the bad query plans are generated right after a bulk load, you must choose a different strategy. In this case the problem is that it takes up to a minute for auto-analyze to kick in and calculate new statistics.

In that case you should run an explicit `ANALYZE` at the end of the bulk load.

Comment: I set the 16 partitioned tables with the parameter which improved, but did not solve the consistency issue.  So for the moment, in the load function, I added table ANALYZE right after the bulk data insertions.  I feel it is not ideal, until I have more time to play with autovacuum parameters such as naptime and max_worker.  Thanks!

Comment: That is the elegant solution. See my updated answer.

Comment: Great.  Thank you so much, Laurenz!